# Weird results when running the script to Find EC2-Classic Resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

When I run the script to find EC2-Classic Resources as per [Finding classic resources](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/ec2-classic-is-retiring-heres-how-to-prepare/) the only output I have is in "Classic Platform" file with the following contents:

```
us-east-1, Disabled
eu-west-1, Disabled
us-west-1, Disabled
ap-southeast-1, Disabled
ap-northeast-1, Disabled
us-west-2, Disabled
sa-east-1, Disabled
ap-southeast-2, Disabled
sa-east-1, Disabled
ap-southeast-2, Disabled
```

I have no idea what this means. Relatively new to AWS so poking about blind. Any ideas?

[image: Screengrab]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there are no EC2-Classic resources in your account.

Unless your account is created before 4th December 2013 or you've specifically asked the support team to enable EC2-Classic, that is the output you should get.

> All AWS accounts created after December 4, 2013, are already VPC-only,
> unless EC2-Classic was enabled as a result of a support request.

I went through the `py-Classic-Resource-Finder.py` and your output does tally with the above points. You simply do not have any EC2-Classic  resources.

Comment: Hi, i updated with a screengrab that seems to suggest the load balancers are of Type "Classic". Am I reading that wrong ?

Comment: That's different Joe. `EC2-Classic` means your instances run in a single, flat network which is shared with other customers as opposed to the newer `Amazon VPC` where your instances run in a virtual private cloud (VPC) that's logically isolated to your AWS account. Classic LBs do not come under the EC2-Classic network.
To learn more about the resources in EC2-Classic and VPC, please refer https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-classic-platform.html